# Get record count in Azure DocumentDb

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

It seems like 'select count(*) from c' in the SQL queries allowed by documentdb in the azure site and through the documentdb explorer (https://studiodocumentdb.codeplex.com/) is not supported.  To date, the only way to get a record count that I have found is from code (see below).  However, there are enough files in our collection now that this is crashing.  Is there a way to get a count on how many documents in a collection that works more than my solution?

```
DocumentClient dc = GetDocumentDbClient();
var databaseCount = dc.CreateDatabaseQuery().ToList();
Database azureDb = dc.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(d => d.Id == Constants.WEATHER_UPDATES_DB_NAME).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

var collectionCount = dc.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(azureDb.SelfLink).ToList();

DocumentCollection update = dc.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(azureDb.SelfLink).Where(c => c.Id == "WeatherUpdates").ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

var documentCount = dc.CreateDocumentQuery(update.SelfLink, "SELECT * FROM c").ToList();

MessageBox.Show("Databases: " + databaseCount.Count().ToString() + Environment.NewLine
                +"Collections: " + collectionCount.Count().ToString() + Environment.NewLine
                + "Documents: " + documentCount.Count().ToString() + Environment.NewLine, 
                 "Totals", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Until the implementation of the "count" keyword, you should do your query in a store procedure on the server. Take care to not get all columns/properties in your query if you want only a count.

Select only the id like;

```
  dc.CreateDocumentQuery(update.SelfLink, "SELECT c.id FROM c")
```

Comment: Please note that `Count` is implemented now, as in the answers below

Answer (score 137):

This is now possible in the year 2017 of our lord.

`SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c`

`[ 1234 ]`

Comment: Be aware that in the month 7 of said year, this eats potentially thousands of RUs. It's rather slow, too.

Comment: Note: 16,400 records in single partition consumes 535 RUs.

Comment: pretty absurd how many RUs it takes to scan something that should be an index.

Comment: I see one response about appending a counter to the latest document, but has anyone else found a way to get an aggregate count without depleting throughput usage?

Comment: In month 9 of said year, I'm still relying on my own logic in a DAL to count create/delete events because the aggregates all appear to be scan driven vs. index driven.

Comment: Could you please explain why do I need to add VALUE to my query? I am used to writing "select count(*) from c" and "select count(1) from c" is very similar to that.

Comment: @ParthShah - from this (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/planet-scale-aggregates-with-azure-documentdb/) page: "(If you’re wondering about the VALUE keyword – all queries return JSON fragments back. By using VALUE, you can get the scalar value of count e.g., 100, instead of the JSON document {"$1": 100})"

Comment: "REQUEST CHARGE 0 RUs" according to azure portal (as of now) and very quick for me

Comment: @nashwan on empty collection?

Comment: @KonstantinSalavatov nope. Just double checked on a large(ish) collection (947497 records) and it still says "0 RUs".

Comment: @nashwan on emulator? Here it takes some RUs even on small collection

Comment: Works with me on a 250 gb database. Costing 0 ru/s

Comment: @SimonZeinstra is your collection a single partition or unlimited multi-partition? I am seeing a couple thousand RUs charges for a multi-partition collection with a couple of hundred thousand documents. I am wondering if you're seeing zero due to being a single partition.

Comment: @RobReagan, it was a partitioned collection. I'm not on this project anymore so cannot check again for you.

Comment: `SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c` is still charging me. My collection is partitioned.

Comment: So azure's portal will lie and say 0 RU's. F12 and look at the calls, seeing the exact same thing in c# client. It makes one call which fails (400) then a second that fails, then it modifies the query to SELECT VALUE [{"item": COUNT(1)}] FROM c
which causes a row scan. But the best part is their UI shows the RU count from the first failed query which is 0.

Comment: SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c costs 2.89 RUs on a 248 record db. Vs 16.51 RUs for SELECT * FROM c. So it does seem like the RU cost has been sorted.

Answer (score 32):

Actually works at this point:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM c
```

Comment: This gives unreliable value.

Comment: This did not work for me. You need to add VALUE in front of COUNT(c.id), like how Micah Williamson said, for this query to work.

Comment: This doesnt appear to work when using multiple paritions

Comment: It works by adding count values returned in continuation. Read the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875869/why-does-select-count1-from-c-change-values-each-time-i-query-it-in-cosmosdb-d/50632568#50632568

Answer (score 14):

This is possible in the same way you write SQL query now,

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM myCollection
```

[image]

**NOTE:** COUNT(1) won't work for a huge datasets.

You can read more about supported queries from **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query)**

Comment: Hi, please tell us how to at least get a rough estimate with huge datasets, without consuming large numbers of RUs: I'm talking tens or hundreds of millions of docs across potentially hundreds of thousands of partitions. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Just to recap - here is example of [Count Stored Procedure via JS](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/Count.js) with continuation support.

And here is one more tool for DocumentDb that's pretty neat: https://github.com/mingaliu/DocumentDBStudio/releases

**Upd Mar 2017**: 
In the latest DDB SDK see [DDB Aggregates press release](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/planet-scale-aggregates-with-azure-documentdb/) there is full support for basic aggregates, without GROUP BY though (for now). 
Here is GIT REpo with examples: https://github.com/arramac/azure-documentdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples/code-samples/Queries

Answer (score 7):

I did a test against a partitioned Document db collection with 200K entities in a single partition. The Collection is configured with 10K RU/second.

Client side queries:

1. `"SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c"`

Time elapsed (ms): 2471 milliseconds 
Total Request Units consumed: 6143.35

Note: This is the fastest and cheapest option. But keep in mind that you would need to handle continuation on the client side and execute next query using the returned continuation token otherwise you may get partial result/count.

2. `"SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM c"`

Time elapsed (ms): 2589
Total RU: 6682.43

Note: This is very close but slightly slower and more expensive.

Server side / Stored Procedure:

1. If you need a stored proc, there is one provided here:
   https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/Count.js

But beware it is problematic.. It internally reads all documents in the collection / partition just to calculate the count. As a result it is much slower and a lot more expensive!

Time elapsed (ms): 8584 milliseconds
Total RU: 13419.31

2. I updated the stored procedure provided in above link to improve the performance. Full Updated Count.js below. The updated stored proc performs way faster and cheaper than the original and it is on par with the best performing client side query (#1 above):

Time elapsed (ms): 2534 milliseconds
Total RU: 6298.36

```
function count(filterQuery, continuationToken) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var maxResult = 500000; 
    var result = 0;

    var q = 'SELECT \'\' FROM root';
    if (!filterQuery) {
        filterQuery = q;
    }

    tryQuery(continuationToken);

    function tryQuery(nextContinuationToken) {
        var responseOptions = { continuation: nextContinuationToken, pageSize: maxResult };

        if (result >= maxResult || !query(responseOptions)) {
            setBody(nextContinuationToken);
        }
    }

    function query(responseOptions) {
        return (filterQuery && filterQuery.length) ?
            collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filterQuery, responseOptions, onReadDocuments) :
            collection.readDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), responseOptions, onReadDocuments);
    }

    function onReadDocuments(err, docFeed, responseOptions) {
        if (err) {
            throw 'Error while reading document: ' + err;
        }

        result += docFeed.length;

        if (responseOptions.continuation) {
            tryQuery(responseOptions.continuation);
        } else {
            setBody(null);
        }
    }

    function setBody(continuationToken) {
        var body = { count: result, continuationToken: continuationToken };
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(body);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently does not exist. I had a similar scenario and we ended up adding a counter to a document attribute that gets updated every time  a document gets added or deleted. You could even make these two steps as part of a store procedure or a trigger if you want atomicity.

Comment: BTW, this and other similar functions are under review by the docdb product group. You can go ahead and vote for that as well. http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333963-add-support-for-aggregate-functions-like-count-su

Comment: As of 29 July 2016, they've started: "We have started work on aggregate support and will update this feedback item as we have more information."

Answer (score 0):

My code count solution is also working...once I just selected the id as a Papa Ours pointed out :)  To get my original post to work, replace this line:

```
var documentCount = dc.CreateDocumentQuery(update.SelfLink, "SELECT * FROM c").ToList();
```

with this line:

```
var documentCount = dc.CreateDocumentQuery(update.SelfLink, "SELECT id FROM c").ToList()
```

I still like the idea of the stored procedure as it will work in the documentdb studio (really cool project :)) - https://studiodocumentdb.codeplex.com/

Comment: This can cause higher RU