# Can I get the count of all records in a Cosmos DB table for a large amount of records?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

Assuming I have approximately 10 million documents in a Cosmos DB SQL table, or 10 million collections in a Cosmos DB Cassandra table, is there any way to view the amount of documents/collections in those tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get record count in Azure DocumentDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745346/get-record-count-in-azure-documentdb)

Comment: answers from that link: 
  "SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM c" , 
"SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use data explorer, you can either count them with the count() function or select the id without any filters. That will cost you X RUs though, so be aware of that.

Comment: SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c