# Get count of records in Azure CosmosDB for large dataset

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49201161/2063755) that you can't use

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1)
FROM c
```

to get the record count for large datasets.
Mine is coming back empty:
[image]

However there are definitely lots of records:
[image]

How can I get the record count in CosmosDB given a large dataset?

Comment: If your query is too large in either resources used or data to send back it will be split into several responses. The response will contain the necessary info to retrieve the other objects in subsequent requests. I've however never seen this for returning the total count as such a query can use the index and is therefore quite optimized. In the Data Explorer such behaviour is indicated by the `load more` button right above the result which you could click a few times to retrieve the next responses.

Comment: There's a "next page" button but it's disabled.

Comment: I'm not sure but is it possible that this problem resulted from throughput? I mean that maybe the container is too big to calculate the size with a small throughput.