# How to receive a SELECT VALUE COUNT query with Java?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb, project-reactor

When I use the [Cosmos website](https://cosmos.azure.com/) to execute the query

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c WHERE 1623736778 <= c.timestamp AND 1623736779 <= c.timestamp
```

I get

```
[
    4
]
```

in the "Results" window. This [makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745346/get-record-count-in-azure-documentdb), since executing

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE 1623736778 <= c.timestamp AND 1623736779 <= c.timestamp
```

returns 4 entries from my database.

How do I receive the result "4" (from SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) ...) in my backend code using Java with Spring Boot? In other words, **given *any* Cosmos repository, how does one access the return from a SELECT VALUE COUNT ... query using Java?**

---

For context, I have a repository class that looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.Query;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.ReactiveCosmosRepository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import myownpackage.MyEntity;

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends ReactiveCosmosRepository<MyEntity, String> {
    ...
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE @startTime <= c.timestamp AND c.timestamp <= @endTime")
    Flux<MyEntity> findInRange(
        @Param("startTime") Long startTime,
        @Param("endTime") Long endTime
    );

    @Query(value = "SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c WHERE @startTime <= c.timestamp AND c.timestamp <= @endTime")
    Flux<MyEntity> countInRange(
        @Param("startTime") Long startTime,
        @Param("endTime") Long endTime
    );
}
```

In my service class I try to do

```
@Autowired private MyRepository repo;
int totalCount = repo.countInRange(1623736778, 1623736779).collectList().block().get(0);
```

so that totalCount == 4, but this causes an error saying "incompatible types: myownpackage.MyEntity cannot be converted to int." Changing the return type of countInRange to int gives "int cannot be dereferenced." There's no issue accessing results from findInRange() in this manner. I used a logger (from slf4j) to run

```
LOGGER.info("\n\nHere is the type we need to know: {}\n\n",
repo.countInRange(1623736778,1623736779).getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

which logs "Here is the type we need to know: reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap", but Googling reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap doesn't reveal any documentation similar to [Flux's documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html).

Comment: can you share the repo

Comment: Unfortunately not because there is sensitive information. But I am wondering generally, for any Cosmos repo, how to access the return from a SELECT VALUE COUNT ... query on backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is of primitive type int and not an Object. Dereferencing is the process of accessing the value referred to by a reference . Since, int is already a value (not a reference), it can not be dereferenced. Try changing the return type as `Flux<Integer>`

Comment: I found success using the return type Flux<Long> (and swapping "int totalCount = ..." out for "Long totalCount = ... ").